# “TypeError: 'unicode' object does not support item assignment” in dicts when scraping via scrapy pipeline

Tags: python, dictionary, unicode, scrapy

I'm trying to build a dictionary of keywords and put it into a scrapy item.

```
'post_keywords':{1: 'midwest', 2: 'i-70',}
```

The point is that this will all go inside a json object later on down the road. I've tried initializing a new blank dictionary first, but that doesn't work.

Pipeline code:

```
tag_count = 0

for word, tag in blob.tags:
    if tag == 'NN':
        tag_count = tag_count+1
        nouns.append(word.lemmatize())

keyword_dict = dict()

key = 0 
for item in random.sample(nouns, tag_count):
    word = Word(item)
    key=key+1
    keyword_dict[key] = word
    item['post_keywords'] = keyword_dict
```

Item:

```
post_keywords = scrapy.Field()
```

Output:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "B:\Mega Sync\Programming\job_scrape\lib\site-packages\twisted\internet\defer.py", line 588, in _runCallbacks
current.result = callback(current.result, *args, **kw)
File "B:\Mega Sync\Programming\job_scrape\cl_tech\cl_tech\pipelines.py", line215, in process_item
item['post_noun_phrases'] = noun_phrase_dict
TypeError: 'unicode' object does not support item assignment
```

It SEEMS like pipelines behave weirdly, like they don't want to run all the code in the pipeline UNLESS all the item assignments check out, which makes it so that my initialized dictionaries aren't created or something.

Comment: The error indicates `item` is a Unicode string, not a dictionary that can be indexed with a keyword.

Comment: @MarkTolonen So based on what you're saying, I can make the item a dict like this: item['post_keywords'] = dict() and it will let me add to it? I tried, and i got the same error. Can you please explain how I would make this work?

Comment: It's not clear to me what you are trying to do.  `item` is a string from your `nouns` random sample.  `D = {}` and `D['post_keywords'] = <something>` is how you create and assign a key/value to a dictionary.

Comment: @MarkTolonen I've added a bit more to the code to show more what I'm doing. I'm trying to make a dictionary titled `post_keywords` with the keywords arranged like this: `{'post_keywords':{1: 'midwest', 2: 'i-70',}}`. The point is that this will all go inside a json object later on down the road. I'll this to the post.

Comment: @MarkTolonen I think I just realized my mistake. I might be using the word `item` for two things, when I shouldn't be. Let me check...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thanks to MarkTolonen for the help.

My mistake was using the variable name 'item' for more than two things.

This works:

```
for thing in random.sample(nouns, tag_count):
            word = Word(thing)
            key = key+1
            keyword_dict[key] = word
            item['post_keywords'] = keyword_dict
```